# Ember Using each

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'am testing Ember, and I see that {{each}} is deprecated now and I shouldu se {{each foo in bar}}.

In my code, when I use only {{each}} everything works fine.

```
<ul>
  {{#each}}
    <li>{{this.url}} - {{this.status}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

But, it log this message:  Please use the keyword form (`{{#each foo in bar}}`) instead. See http://emberjs.com/guides/deprecations/#toc_more-consistent-handlebars-scope for more details.

So, I updated my code to:

```
<ul>
  {{#each b in billing}}
    <li>{{b.url}} - {{b.status}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

And seems that billing is empty or something like that.

My Model:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

// billing.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
  status: DS.attr('string'),
  url: DS.attr('string')
});
```

My Routes:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
        model: function() {
                return this.store.find('billing');
        }
});
```

Ember console: http://prntscr.com/6ibgfh

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the each helper doesn't know what `billing` is.

`{{#each b in billing}}`

Should be:

`{{#each b in model}}`

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. The doc (http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/displaying-a-list-of-items/) don't should  be updated?

Comment: I don't think it needs to be updated... they're assuming that you know what properties are on your controller, they can't document every one of your use cases...

Answer (score 0):

There is also a new ["block param" syntax](http://emberjs.com/blog/2014/12/08/ember-1-9-0-released.html#toc_block-params), so that if you have a model defined as follows:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return { notes: ['red', 'yellow', 'blue'] };
  }
});
```

You can loop through it as follows:

```
{{#each notes as |note| }}
  {{ note }}
{{/each}}
```

Working example [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/maloca/1/edit?html,js,output)